# How to set up plotly.js in nuxt SSR?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, plotly.js

I'm trying to set up plotly.js in nuxt but whatever I do I get this cryptic error

`self is not defined`

I tried to install `plotly.js` and `plotly.js-dist` same error shows.

I would prefer to make custom build so I tried like this in nuxt plugins:

```js
// here we use custom partial bundle
import plotly from 'plotly.js/lib/core';
import barpolar from 'plotly.js/lib/barpolar';

export default function (_, inject) {
  plotly.register([barpolar]);
  inject('plotly', plotly);
}
```

but whenever I register nuxt plugin site crashes with aforementioned error.
Even not going down custom bundle route, and using dist lib still fails just the same.

I also tried not to employ nuxt plugins system but to import manually and to set up, same things happen.

I also added `ify-loader` as recommended here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly-webpack

and this is my `nuxt.config.js` in regards to webpack plugin:

```js
build: {
    extend(config, { isClient }) {
      console.log('config :>> ', config);
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          'ify-loader',
          'transform-loader?plotly.js/tasks/compress_attributes.js',
        ],
      });
    },
  },
```

still no luck.

I presume this is problem with webpack 5 and plotly.js not working well together in default setup but I have no idea how to solve this.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this wasn't working is that plotly tried to access document, and in SSR that would obviously fail.

So to fix this I just had to assign plugin in client only mode like this:

```js
plugins: [
    // other plugins
    { src: '~/plugins/plotly', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

and it worked.

Comment: I'm not able to get plotly running in nuxt 2.  I would long for you to give a step by step guide. So far I did 'yarn add plotly' and 'yarn add @nuxt/webpack', added the above section to the build section in nuxt.conf.js, created the plugin/plotly.js like above and added the plugin assignement in nuxt.config.js. Still get "self is not defined"

Comment: @timitalia you should have plugins folder in root (as per path shown above), and you have to inject plotly inside.

And later you just paste this plugin section with client mode in nuxt.config.js. 
reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-plugins/